# Bug in splitting sum

Tags: bugs, summation

**Bug introduced in 9.0, persisting through 12.3.1**

---

I was trying to evaluate the following sum.

$$
\frac{2}{m}\sum_{\substack{\text{odd }k\\1\leq k\leq m-1}} f\left(\frac{m+2+\sqrt{m^2-4k+4}}{2}\right)+f\left(\frac{m+2-\sqrt{m^2-4k+4}}{2}\right).
$$

And I wrote the following Mathematica code.

```
2/m Sum[f[1/2 (2 + m + Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])] +
        f[1/2 (2 + m - Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}]
```

Then I tested it with $f(x)=x^2$ and $m=60$. I defined

```
f[x_] = x^2
```

and evaluated

```
2/m Sum[f[1/2 (2 + m + Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])] +
     f[1/2 (2 + m - Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}] /.
  m -> 60 // N
```

which gave

```
(* 3664. *)
```

However, if I split the sum into two parts, it ends with a very different value:

```
 2/m Sum[f[1/2 (2 + m + Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}] +
 2/m Sum[f[1/2 (2 + m - Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}] /. m->60 //N
```

gives

```
(* 4.6048 + 1.12029*10^-13 I *)
```

What is the problem here? There seems to be no problem if $f(x)=x^p$ and $p$ is fractional. I tried $p=1.1$, $1.5$, $2.1$, etc., and both answers agree. Looks like the problem occurs when $p$ is an integer...

Comment: I still get the discrepancy on 11.0.0 (Windows). You see the bug fixed on your side?

Comment: @Xavier Sorry, the bug of the main thread post still exists... however I cannot reproduce the bug of the last piece of code in the last reply...

Comment: The bug is introduced in v9: https://i.stack.imgur.com/18iZW.png

Comment: In fact the bug is gone when x^2 becomes x^2.000001 (wait for it).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a symbolic calculation bug in there:

Let's define:

```
plus[k_, m_]  := f[1/2 (2 + m + Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])];
minus[k_, m_] := f[1/2 (2 + m - Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])];
```

While

```
(With[{m = 60}, Sum[minus[k, m], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}]] // N) ==
               (Sum[minus[k, m], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}] /. m -> 60 // N)

(* True *)
```

on the other hand:

```
(With[{m = 60}, Sum[plus[k, m], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}]] // N) ==
               (Sum[plus[k, m], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}] /. m -> 60 // N)

(* False *)
```

So the term with the `HurwitzZeta[ ..]` functions is in error.

Comment: This example has been fixed in MMA 11.2.0. I got `True` for the 'on the other hand' expression. But the problem in the original problem still exists

Comment: With v12.1 on a Mac I get `True` for both tests.

Comment: @BobHanlon Something strange happens here. If I start Mathematica, with a clean kernel, I run this code, I get `True` for both. However, if I run the code in my original post first, then I run the code in this reply, I get `True` for the first one and `False` for the second one.

Comment: @user58955 - On checking, it depends on whether `f` is defined. Just running code above (`f` not defined) gives `True` for both. Including `f[x_] = x^2;` gives `True` and `False` respectively.

Answer (score 10):

This is interesting! Here's a partial answer (so more of a long comment):

```
Clear[f]
f[x_] = x^2;
Sum[f[1/2 (2 + m + Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}]
```

and the output is:

[image]

whereas

```
Sum[f[1/2 (2 + m - Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}]
```

doesn't evaluate (i.e. it returns itself), and

```
Sum[f[1/2 (2 + m + Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])] + f[1/2 (2 + m - Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}]
(* -(1 + Floor[1/2 (-2 + m)]) (-2 - 2 m - m^2 + 2 Floor[1/2 (-2 + m)]) *)
```

You will note that if you set the terms with the `HurwitzZeta` function to zero, then these two expressions are identical up to a factor of `1/2`. The `HurwitzZeta` functions would cancel each other out if the arguments for two of those functions didn't have the `Floor[m/2]` pieces in them.

---

Now, if we evaluate the sums symbolically first (the `2/m` doesn't make a difference), we get

```
Clear[f, f1]
f1 = Sum[f[1/2 (2 + m + Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])] + 
         f[1/2 (2 + m - Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}];
f1 = f1 /. m -> 60 // Expand;
f[x_] = x^2;
f1 // N
(* 109920. *)
```

and

```
Clear[f]
f1 = Sum[f[1/2 (2 + m + Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}] + 
  Sum[f[1/2 (2 + m - Sqrt[4 - 4 k + m^2])], {k, 1, -1 + m, 2}];
f1 = f1 /. m -> 60 // Expand;
f[x_] = x^2;
f1 // N
(* 109920. *)
```

which indicates to me that they *should* be equal.

---

On the other hand,

```
Sum[(1/2 (2 + 60 + Sqrt[4 - 4 k + 60^2]))^2 + (1/2 (2 + 60 - Sqrt[4 - 4 k + 60^2]))^2, {k, 1, -1 + 60, 2}] // N
Sum[(1/2 (2 + 60 - Sqrt[4 - 4 k + 60^2]))^2, {k, 1, -1 + 60, 2}] +
   Sum[(1/2 (2 + 60 - Sqrt[4 - 4 k + 60^2]))^2, {k, 1, -1 + 60, 2}] // N
(* 109920 *)
(* 71.3744 *)
```

---

I perhaps suspect a bug. However, I also suspect that if the second sum evaluated, it would have terms that would cancel the `HurwitzZeta` functions in the first term, so perhaps it's instead some sort of problem there.

Comment: The bug in the 'on the other hand' part seems fixed in MMA 11.0.0

Comment: In MMA 11.2.0, the second expression in the 'on the other hand' part evaluates to `138.144061345985`...

Comment: @user58955. Actually, it does in my copy of V10.0.1, too, so I'm not sure what version I used in this answer. Probably V8.